# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List - Delete symbol on each item in list

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

I would like there to be a red X next to the users email address. I know I can just add a delete button. But if possible, I think it would be better for the user to just click the X button next to the email address. Is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
List emailList = new List(composite_2, SWT.BORDER);
emailList.add("chris@gmail.com");
FormData fd = new FormData();
fd.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
emailList.setLayoutData(fd);
```

Comment: `List` only supports text. JFace `TableViewer` or SWT `Table` can have images.

Comment: Okay, I will use a Table instead.